# Should execution continue if array is empty?

Tags: programming-practices, array

Just a general programming best practices question.

If I have a function like that takes in an array of items and the function then calls a series of other functions which filter and act on the items in the array, should execution continue if at any point we are acting on an empty array? 
E.g.

```
arrayItems = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

filtered = filterItems(arrayItems) // Now we have [1,2]
validItems = validate(filtered) // Now we have []
processed = process(validItems) // Acting on []
```

Should I be checking for an empty array at each step before executing the next function or is it fine to continue if the later functions can handle an empty input?

Comment: An empty array is perfectly good data -- no need to check for that, until you want to know if it is empty, or, to extract an element.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Checking against an empty array will increase the size of your code considerably and make it harder to read. The benefit is a tiny improvement in efficiency, but all you save is the price of a few function calls, which are probably insignificant compared to the time it takes to execute those functions even a few times (and you still have to add the cost of the `empty()` call). Therefore, overall it is much better to leave out the check and just let all your filters do nothing the normal way - by iterating over the empty collection.

Comment: Yes! While special-casing might not always have a performance-cost/benefit (measure!), the true cost is increased complexity.

Answer (score 6):

The question is whether the operation would be meaningful for an empty array.

Take the function `count()` which returns the number of elements. That is meaningful for an empty array - the count of items would then be 0. So no need to special case the empty array. But take `max()` which returns the largest value in an array. That is not really meaningful for an empty array. So you will have to check for that.

Comment: Well, the minimum value for the type might make a suitable result for maximum of empty range. Or maybe floating point `NaN`. Or perhaps that really is an error.